# How to import live data into python using pd.read_html such as that of Corona?

Tags: python, pandas, choropleth

I am new to python and would like to work on data plotting. I want to plot a live data of COVID-19 using either google data or world meter. I am using pandas and plotly_graph_objs.

How should I import live data into code so that further I can use it for Choropleth?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode,iplot
init_notebook_mode(connected = True)

df = pd.read_csv('owid-covid-data.csv')
df.head()
data = dict(type='choropleth',
           colorscale = 'Viridis',
           reversescale = True,
           locations = df['location'],
           locationmode = 'country names',
           z = df['new_cases'],
            #zz = data['total_deaths_per_million'],
           text = df['iso_code'],
           colorbar = {'title':'COVID'})

layout = dict(title='COVID-19',
             geo = dict(showframe=True,
                       projection = {'type':'mercator'}))

choromap = go.Figure(data=[data],layout=layout)
iplot(choromap,validate=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch the data first and then read into a DataFrame using a method suitable for your data.

e.g.

```
import requests

countries = requests.get('https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries')
df = pd.read_html(countries.text)[-1]

df

Country,Other   TotalCases  NewCases    TotalDeaths NewDeaths   TotalRecovered  ActiveCases Serious,Critical    Tot Cases/1M pop    Deaths/1M pop   TotalTests  Tests/ 1M pop
0   World   2181308 +95,022 145471.0    +6,996  547069.0    1488768 56602.0 280.00  18.7    NaN NaN
1   China   82341   +46 3342.0  NaN 77892.0 1107    95.0    57.00   2.0 NaN NaN
2   USA 677570  +29,567 34617.0 +2,174  57508.0 585445  13369.0 2047.00 105.0   3398140.0   10266.0
3   Spain   184948  +4,289  19315.0 +503    74797.0 90836   7371.0  3956.00 413.0   930230.0    19896.0
4   Italy   168941  +3,786  22170.0 +525    40164.0 106607  2936.0  2794.00 367.0   1178403.0   19490.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
209 British Virgin Islands  3   NaN NaN NaN 2.0 1   NaN 99.00   NaN NaN NaN
210 Caribbean Netherlands   3   NaN NaN NaN NaN 3   NaN 114.00  NaN 10.0    381.0
211 Saint Pierre Miquelon   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   NaN 173.00  NaN NaN NaN
212 Yemen   1   NaN NaN NaN NaN 1   NaN 0.03    NaN NaN NaN
213 Total:  2181308 +95,022 145471.0    +6,996  547069.0    1488768 56602.0 279.80  18.7    NaN NaN
214 rows × 12 columns
```

Not sure about Google data, whether they offer an API or you need to scrape the data.

Comment: This one is new to me "import requests" but i will try for sure. Thanks

Comment: It's a fairly popular python library.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to get daily virus stats from Data Repository by Johns Hopkins CSSE at Github : https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19

Alternative would be to parse data from WorldMeters or similar site.

Also check out [resources at Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/covid-19-contributions)

Comment: I actually went there too. plotted it for 16 april 2020 IST. but then again I want to update it automatically. But thanks. :-)